# Removing last comma every line

Tags: java, csv

I am having trouble dealing with trailing commas in my code, I've tried one solution from this website but still couldn't solve it. Any help would be great.

Here's my code.

```
    String delimiter = "!@#$";
    for ( String data1: overall.keySet() )
    resultString += data1 + "," + overall.get(data1).toString() +  System.getProperty("line.separator");

    resultString = resultString.replace("," + delimiter , "");
```

Here's the one which I've found on this web, which only remove the last comma at the last line.

```
resultString += data1 + "," + overall.get(data1).toString() +  System.getProperty("line.separator");

resultString = resultString.replaceAll(",$", "");
```

My current output is

```
a,b,
c,d,
e,f,
```

Instead of

```
a,b
c,d
e,f
```

Comment: Where is the last comma coming from? Is that part of the return value of `overall.get(data1).toString()`? Why not fix that function instead?

Comment: @GregHewgill i believe its from the part `data1 + ","`

Comment: So then is `overall.get(data1).toString()` returning an empty string? If so, wouldn't you want to *keep* the last comma?

Comment: @GregHewgill I was told to remove it so, yeah...

Comment: So you were simply told to remove it, and you're going to do that at this point in your code without even learning where it's coming from? That's not what programming is about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `replaceAll()` instead of `replace()` --> `resultString = resultString.replaceAll(",$", "");` because `replaceAll()` takes `regex` where `$` means end of input.

Example :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "abc,def,";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll(",$", ""));
}
```

O/P :

```
abc,def
```

EDIT : Based on your code.

You should probably change your code to :

```
 for ( String data1: overall.keySet() ){
    resultString += data1 + "," + overall.get(data1).toString() +  System.getProperty("line.separator");
    resultString = resultString.replaceAll(",$", "");
}
```

Comment: Oops, that my 2nd part of the codes supposed to be `replaceAll()` i only removes the last line's comma.

Comment: @justalazyguy - I saw your output now. Do you have a loop or something?

Comment: before the resultString is a for loop to loop through every line of data.

Comment: @justalazyguy - then use *our code* there. Also, show us the `for-loop`

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the last character if every line as the comma:

```
resultString = resultString.substring(0, resultString.length()-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to remove trailing comma from a String having comma separated values you can try `replaceAll`:

```
String str = "a,b,c,d,e,f,";
str = str.replaceAll(",$", "");
System.out.println(str);
```

It prints:
`a,b,c,d,e,f`

This solution also handles the empty list (empty string) gracefully, as opposed to `lastIndexOf` / `substring` solutions which requires special treatment of such case. In the above solution `$` is a special symbol for matching the end of the string.

If you have an array of `String` then use it in a loop:

```
        String[] stringsArray = new String[] {"a,b", "c,d", "e,f"};
        for(String str : stringsArray) {
            str = str.replaceAll(",$", "");
            System.out.println(str);
        }
```

And output is:

`a,b
c,d
e,f`

Comment: It only removes the last row's last comma.

Comment: You will have to execute it in a loop then.